# Reuse Header and Footer across pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I have all the menu at the header section. On click of a menu link only the content changes but the header and footer remains the same.
I am thinking of two options.

1. Put the content section inside an iframe.
2. include('header.jsp');

   // render page specific content ...

   include('footer.jsp');

Is there any better way to do this ? Will something like jQuery .load() give a significant improvement in performance ?

Comment: The question I would start with is "do I want to be able to access any page through a URL?". If so, iframes and AJAX are not the right tools.

Comment: @JBNizet, Ajax is the right tool, with `pushstate`

Comment: No here the user wont be able to access any page through a URL apart from the log in page

Comment: @Petah: alright, so Ajax could be used, provided you also make it possible to access every page through a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's load is a good option, just make sure you load your HTML before any of your javascript.  All you need is the content section to load into, for example:

With the content section:

```
<div id='content'></div>
```

And the code below:

```
$('#content').load('/includes/content2.html', function(){
    // load scripts here
});
```